# Save screenshots taken with FFmpeg into Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

In my python app I take screenshots of videos. I save them locally and it works just fine but now I want to save them in an Amazon S3 bucket.

```
subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-ss", "00:00:30", "-i", src, "-map", "0:v", "-vframes", "1", "pipe:pic.jpeg | aws s3 cp - s3://mypublicbucket"])
```

I get an `Unable to find a suitable output format` when running this command. What I try to do is to upload the picture straight into my public amazon bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save your outpout as a `stdout` and send it to Amazon S3 with boto3.

Something like this:

```
video = subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-ss", "00:00:50", "-i", src, "-f", "image2", "-vframes", "1", "-"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

client = boto3.client('s3',
                        aws_access_key_id="YOUR_KEY_ID",
                        aws_secret_access_key= "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY")

response = client.put_object(Body=video.stdout, Bucket="your-bucket", Key="pic.jpeg")
```

Pleace take note of the `"-"` in the FFmpeg command, it means you want the outpout as a `stdout`. `"-f", "image2"` is for your output format, a picture, if you need diferent output format just run `ffmpeg -muxers` and you will find one that suits your needs.